# Commvault, how to generate a report by time scheduled?

Tags: windows, backup, database, report, commvault

I'm using commvault at the moment to manage backups, but i need to creata a report of some kind that can show me the days of the week , and what server is backing up at that moment.

A bit like this:

Monday

8-9 pm   |   windowserver1,windowserver2

9-10 pm  |   linuxserver1,linuxserver2here

10-11 pm  |

11-12 pm  |  fsbackup1, fsbackup2

Can somebody help me ?  Thanks in advance!

Regards,

Dennis